# C#: Getting black image after initiliazing Image with Bitmapimage in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmap, bitmapimage

Hi Developer,

I have an issue to display a bitmap image in my System.Windows.Controls.Image,

Am I using Pixelformat correctly?

I am able to display the image, but it shows me just a black rectangle.
I am trying to get the image from the Scanner.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(displayW, displayH, image.PixelFormat);



VCardScan.MainWindow.AppWindow.setImageSource(BitmapToImageSource(b));





                public void setImageSource(BitmapImage bitmap)
                        {
                            CardBox.Source = bitmap;
                        }



   BitmapImage BitmapToImageSource(Bitmap bitmap)
        {

            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())

            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(bitmap.ToString());
                bitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
                memory.Position = 0;
                BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();

                bitmapimage.BeginInit();
                bitmapimage.StreamSource = memory;


                bitmapimage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmapimage.EndInit();


                return bitmapimage;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you check the original Bitmap to see if its valid? E.g. just save it to a FileStream.

Comment: I saved the Image from the original Bitmap on the Filesystem and it saves a black Image as it is shown on the WPF, but when I use the export method from the SDK it saves the Image fine. How can I solve this?